# adding elements of another arraylist by recursion-java

Tags: java, list, recursion, arraylist

Here is a method that is supposed to simply create a new ArrayList copying all the elements of parameter ArrayList arrlist, which I think I've done correctly.

```
public ArrayList<T> copy (ArrayList<T> arrlist) {
        ArrayList<T> um=new ArrayList<T>();
        for (int i=0;i<arrlist.size();i++)
            um.add(arrlist.get(i));
        return um;
```

However, I'd like to write this exact same method using recursion only with no loops. Here is what I wrote. The copy method uses a recursive helper method.

```
public ArrayList<T> copy(ArrayList<T> arrlist) {
    return copy(arrlist,0); 
}

private ArrayList<T> copy(ArrayList<T> arrlist, int n) {
    ArrayList<T> um=new ArrayList<T>();
    if (n<arrlist.size())
        um.add(list.get(n));
    return copy(list,n+1); 
}
```

Except this does not work. Any suggestions or hints?

Comment: What is error there?

Comment: "doesn't work" in what way? Describe the specific problem you're asking for help with

Comment: Is there a base case to this recursion?  Or does it just call itself forever?

Comment: Just about to say the same thing. No base case, can't see this ever terminating.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iterating through arraylists with recursion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26478385/iterating-through-arraylists-with-recursion)

Comment: @DavidWallace Wouldn't it stop once n is equal to arrlist.size()...?

Comment: no, it will still hit the line "return copy(list,n+1);"

Comment: um is allocated in each recursive call also when will the recursive method stop? I can figure that

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are creating a new `ArrayList` in every recursion. And you are not returning it anywhere.

What you should do is, in the helper method, also pass the target `ArrayList` as a parameter, and add to it rather than a new one.

(And of course, don't forget to return when you're done).

Answer (score 1):

You are allocating (ArrayList um=new ArrayList();) array list in every recursive call.
Also I can not see when the recursive function will stop to call itself

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
private void copy(ArrayList<T> src, ArrayList<T> src_copy, int n) {
  if (n>=0){
    src_copy.add(src.get(n));
    copy(src,src_copy, n-1); 
   }
 }
```

Then, use it as below :

```
ArrayList<T> src = ... ; //your arrayList
ArrayList<T> src_copy = new ArrayList<T>();
if (src != null && src.size() > 0) {
   copy(src, src_copy, src.size()-1);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what error you are getting. but I think this should work.

```
public ArrayList<T> copy(ArrayList<T> arrlist) {
    ArrayList<T> um = new ArrayList<T>();
    return copy(arrlist, um, 0); 
}

private ArrayList<T> copy(ArrayList<T> arrlist, ArrayList<T> um, int n) {
    if (n < arrlist.size())
        um.add(arrlist.get(n));
    else
        return um;
    return copy(arrlist, um, n+1); 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

See the below basic recursive fibonacci function:

```
public int fib(int n) {
    if(n <= 1) {
        return n;
    } else {
        return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
    }
}
```

This works as a recursive function because it has a base case, a path by which the function will return a result that is not another call to itself. You'll need a base case to complete the recursive call when a condition is met, and return the results.